# Jupyter notebook stuck after pip install google-colab on local

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-colaboratory

I installed google.colab using pip install google.colab in my terminal, after doing this the jupyter notebook that I was working on stopped working. When I opened a new jupyter notebook, I could not run any code. When I tried to run any code it stayed stuck on In[*]. Before installing google.colab my notebooks were working fine. I tried restarting my kernel but that did not work. Then I tried uninstalling it by pip uninstall google-colab, which uninstalled it succesfully, but did not fix the issue.
Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

To me the same thing happened, and I found the answer fixing everything at:

[pip installed google.colab and now unable to run code on Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583918/pip-installed-google-colab-and-now-unable-to-run-code-on-jupyter-notebook)

It seemed like some dependencies downgraded after colab installation. Just upgrading all the packages from pip solved the issue to me.