# Unable to connect to kernel while using Jupyter notebook on VS Code, because of Google Colab. it is uninstalled, but still fails to connect to kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, pyenv

I have an issue similar to this post: [pip installed google.colab and now unable to run code on Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583918/pip-installed-google-colab-and-now-unable-to-run-code-on-jupyter-notebook)

Same as him, I installed google.colab using pip install google.colab in the terminal of VS Code, after doing this the jupyter notebook that I was working on stopped working. When I opened a new jupyter notebook, I could not run any code. When I tried to run any code it stayed stuck on connecting to the kernel. Before installing google.colab my notebooks were working fine. I tried restarting my kernel but that did not work. I also used pip uninstall google.colab but that gives the following: WARNING: Skipping google.colab as it is not installed. Then I tried uninstalling it by pip uninstall google-colab, which uninstalled it succesfully, but did not fix the issue. Everything here happened in VS Code.

As i am using pyenv to control my py version, I am trying to update my python version from 3.7.3 to 3.9.0, in the hope that i can connect to this new version(or kernel). But it returns an error:

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.6 using python-build 20180424)
```

Therefore, right now, i have 2 issues here,

1. the colab causing my jypter notebook to crash in CS Code, I have uninstalled colab, but the kernel still won't connect no matter which kernel i choose.
2. the pyenv won't install a new version of python.

Please help !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can happen post OS upgrade and can make services that were running well before, useless. did you perform an upgrade of the OS ?

Comment: thank you Jinja, nope , i didn't. But i ran safe mode a week ago, because of my Mac lost the camera function. Then i restored the same exact version 10.14.6 OS, and my camera came back.

Comment: I see @yts61, anyway check this out it is worth trying [link] (https://www.studytonight.com/post/solved-mac-os-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-missing-xcrun)
you can also check config.log maybe you will find more elements that highlight what's happening

Comment: thank you Jinja, but why is Xcode? i checked it out, but i don't understand. Would you please tell me more?

Comment: I think that either the install or the uninstal of colab wasn't done properly somehow which damed the xcrun, I am not really sure but i think it is worth the try

Comment: Thank you , it works ! and now i have the new python version 3.9.0, and the kernel is connected, and problem is solved!

Comment: Great to know ! my pleasure